# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2

Tags: ant, findbugs

Getting following exceptions while running findbugs in ant task.
I have findbugs jar of 0.7 version and jsr305 jar of 1.3.8 version in my findbugs home. Let me know if i am missing anything
findbugs:

> [findbugs] Executing findbugs from ant task
>    [findbugs] Running FindBugs...
>    [findbugs] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/umd/cs/findbugs/FindBugs2
>    [findbugs] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2
>    [findbugs]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>    [findbugs]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    [findbugs]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>    [findbugs]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>    [findbugs]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>    [findbugs]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>    [findbugs] Could not find the main class: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2. Program will exit.
>    [findbugs] Exception in thread "main"
>    [findbugs] Output saved to findbugs.xml

```
<property name="build" value="C:\.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\child\classes" />
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/> 
<target name="findbugs" >
    <findbugs home="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\findbugsant" 
              output="xml" 
              outputFile="findbugs.xml"> 
        <sourcePath path="C:\.hudson\jobs\project\workspace"/> 
        <class location="${build}" /> 
    </findbugs> 
</target>
```

Comment: Looks like a classpath isuse. Can you post the contents of your build.xml?

Comment: <property name="build" value="C:\.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\child\classes" />   
<taskdef name="findbugs"                                                                                 classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>   
     <target name="findbugs" >
       <findbugs home="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\findbugsant"
        output="xml" outputFile="findbugs.xml">
        <sourcePath   path="C:\.hudson\jobs\project\workspace"/>
         <class location="${build}" />
         </findbugs> 
       </target>

Comment: Can you edit your original posting and list the contents of the c:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\findbugsant directory.

Answer (score 9):

In your taskdef, use the classpath attribute to specify where exactly the jar that contains findbugs class (FindBugsTask) is located. Try something like this:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classpath="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\findbugsant\findbugs-ant.jar" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" />
```

The findbugs jar I have is **findbugs-ant.jar**, so check this out in the proposed solution and use the findbugs filename that applies to your case, and you should be ok.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. That findbugs jar may have a different name, depending on the package it came with. e.g. `C:\workspace\3rdPartyJars\findbug`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a installation/configuration of `findbugs` with `ant`.

From the snippet above, it looks like the `findbugs` has been *installed* in `lib` subfolder of ant, rather than just `findbugs-ant.jar` being copied to it as [documented](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html).